# Error when using PhantomJS to get html output after execution of highlight.js

Tags: phantomjs, highlight.js

I am using PhantomJS to get the html source of a page after the execution of some javascript code (namely highlight.js). Note that I'm relatively new to the use of javascript.

Here is the code of the html page ("aaaaa.html"):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/highlight/styles/vs2015.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <code class="language-c">
                extern int myFunction (double toto1, double toto2);
            </code>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript part executed by phantomJS:

```
var system = require('system');

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        page.includeJs("./libs/highlight/highlight.min.js", function() {
            var content = page.evaluate(function () {
                var pretags = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
                for (var i = 0; i < pretags.length; i++) {
                    if (pretags[i].parentNode.localName == "pre") {
                        hljs.highlightElement(pretags[i]);
                    }
                }
                system.stdout.write(page.content);
                return page.content;
            });
            system.stdout.write(content);
            phantom.exit(0);
        })
    } else {
        system.stderr.write('ERROR Unable to load the url!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
};

page.open("aaaaa.html", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {});
});
```

When I execute this script I keep having the following error (using page.onError callback):
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hljs`

I don't understand how to fix this. I thought this was an issue with having to wait for the page to completely load before writing the content (hence the use of onLoadFinished) but apparently not, or I am missing something...
I've also tried window.setTimeout
I've checked that the path to highlight.min.js is correct (although I am not even sure that this is the right way to go to call this javascript inside the phantomjs script).

Any help will be much appreciated